# sublime text 3 anaconda stop working after restart

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I have installed Anaconda package using package controle.

I have the following user settings for the package:

```
{
    /*
        No Autoformatting
    */
    "auto_formatting": false,
    "autoformat_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E501"
    ],
    "pep8_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E501"
    ],
    /*
        No Linting (this is done by sublinter-flake8)
    */
    "anaconda_linting": false,
    "anaconda_linter_underlines": false,
    "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
    "display_signatures": true,
    /*
        Use anaconda for code completion
        Suppress sublime completions
    */
    "disable_anaconda_completion": false,
    "suppress_word_completions": true,
    "suppress_explicit_completions": true,
    "enable_signatures_tooltip" : true,
    "merge_signatures_and_doc" : true,
    /*
        Others
    */
    "complete_parameters": false
}
```

Right after installation The anaconda autocompletion works:
[image]

but after restart of sublime text 3 it stop working:

[image]

sublime text 3 version - 3.2.2  build 3211
could you please help to understand what I'm doing wrong or what settings need to add to make it working after restart?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`)? Are you sure you're opening and working in a Pyhon file (the bottom right of the window should say `Python` and not `Plain text`)?

Comment: No errors in the console. and Yes I'm sure that I'm working with python.

Comment: Did you wait for a while to see if the Anaconda completions showed up? Sometimes it takes a little while for it to index the module.